# error while compiling a c++ code which is called inside of a python code, with boost python

Tags: c++, makefile, boost-python

I started a project in Python and I want to work with some image objects. I want to call some C++ functions in my Python's code. After some research, I decided to use the Python Boost library to call a C++ function in my Python code.

My Boost version is : libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1.
and I am using Python v3.6.

I wrote my C++ code like this in my CppProject.cpp:

```
char const* myMethod() {
    // do some operations ...


    return "It is Done";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(CppProject) {
    boost::python::def("getTryString", myMethod); // boost::python is the namespace
}
```

also, I created my CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(NativeLib CppProject)
FILE(COPY MyProject.py DESTINATION .) # See the whole tutorial to understand this line
```

and finally, this is my Python code in MyProject.py:

```
import NativeLib
# some preprocess
print (NativeLib.getTryString)
```

After writing the code, I created a directory with the name build.
and in that directory, I ran this command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

After that and before I run my Python code, I did make it and finally, I ran my python's code but segmentation fault occurred!

Could someone help me with solving this error?

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve]? Also, it might matter which versions of Python and Boost you use.

Comment: Unrelated to your *current* question, but the Python script doesn't really call the function.

Comment: When you create a [mcve] to show us, also include the *full* and *complete* error output from building that example, including any possible informational notes. And don't forget that the example needs to show us all the `#include` directives you have (in short, it should be possible for us to copy-paste it and try to replicate the error).

Comment: You are not including the boost header file

Comment: @someprogrammerdude If you copy my codes in your editor and do my instruction's which I told, you can see this error. All things are introduced in my question. :)

Comment: You say that you "wrote my c++ code **like** this" (emphasis mine)... Is that really the *exact* code you using? Without including any header files?

Comment: Any guessing is not helpful. Please provide a [mcve], which everyone can take as it is, compile it and get the results you get. Actually, this is a requirement for asking here! Without it, a question is considered off-topic. This helps to weed out bad questions, like those that are easily solved once you reduce the problem.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude yes. because this is just a test to wire a wrapper for my c++ function. First I just wrote a simple c++ function which is do nothing. just return a char*.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Thanks for your answer, but as I edited my question, now i have a segmentation fault after including boost::python::def.
do you have any opinion?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs all symbols you use in your program to be declared before you use them. If you use a symbol which have't been declared it will give you an error because it doesn't know about it.

Now when you use `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`, that symbol is unknown by the compiler, and the whole statement is therefore syntactically wrong.

You must include the Boost header files that defines the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro, as well as `boost::python::def`.

Comment: You are right. I added #include <boost/python.hpp> to my c++ code and then it makes correctly. but when I ran my python' code, segmentation fault occurred.